# Firebase "Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object" with object containing ArrayList of DocumentReference

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to pass to another activity a `User` object containing an Arraylist of Firestore `DocumentReference` and when I start the activity I got this exception.
I'm not using Parceleable so can you confirm that this error is due to the complexity of the object to pass and I must absolutely use the Parcels instead of simple Serializeable?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error because [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) class does not implement `Parceleable` nor `Serializable`.

If you need to serialize a `DocumentReference` object you need to use its [getPath()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#getPath()) method to get a String that describes the document's location in the database. To deserialize that path String back into a `DocumentReference` object, use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference ref = rootRef.document(path);
```

Please see official documentation for [FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(path)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#document(java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: Ok, so I need to mofidy my User POJO to redefine my User object with an ArrayList<String> instead ArrayList<DocumentReference>, Thanks.

Comment: Yes, because all of your object in your model class should be serializable. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer solved the problem for me. I just want to share my implementation for couple of methods to handle the Parcel on the fly! and still have the array as `ArrayList<DocumentReference>`.

```
private ArrayList<String> docRefToString(ArrayList<DocumentReference> products) {
    ArrayList<String> newProducts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (DocumentReference product : products) {
        newProducts.add(product.getPath());
    }
    return newProducts;
}

private ArrayList<DocumentReference> docStringToDoc(ArrayList<String> products) {
    ArrayList<DocumentReference> newProducts = new ArrayList<DocumentReference>();
    for (String product : products) {
        newProducts.add(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(product));
    }
    return newProducts;
}
```

And in the `Parcel` implementation ..

```
private Request(Parcel in) {
    ...
    ArrayList<String> strProducts = in.createStringArrayList();
    this.products = docStringToDoc(strProducts);
    ...
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    ...
    dest.writeStringList(docRefToString(this.products));
    ...
}
```