# Firestore DocumentReference Serialization

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a pojo which maps a firestore document. That document contains references to other documents of other collection.

```
class Game(var local: String? = null, var visitor: String? = null,
        var events: MutableList<DocumentReference> = mutableListOf(), var date: Date? = null): Serializable
```

The problem is that DocumentReference isn't serializable. I've read that I can save the path as String and then create the object myself(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(path)), but then in the firestore is no longer a field of type Reference.

So my question, Is this the good approach? Also, Does it matter that the field is a String rather than a Reference?

Regards, Diego

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is, is this the good approach?

Yes it is. The most important part in a `DocumenetReference` is the string path. If you serialize that, you can reconstitute a DocumentReference object, very easy.

As the conclusion, if you need to serialize a `DocumentReference` object, use DocumentReference's [getPath()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#getPath()) method to get a literal String that represents the document's location in the database. To deserialize that path String back into a `DocumentReference` object, simply use [FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(path)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#document(java.lang.String)).

**Edit:**

> This implies that the field in the database is now a String instead of Reference.

That's right.

> Does it matter? I suppose that being a Reference must have some type of advantage.

Yes, since now the property is of type a String, you cannot take advantage of what [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) class provides anymore. But this is the workaround that can help you achieve what you want. String class is serializable while DocumentReference's is not.

Comment: This implies that the field in the database is now a String instead of Reference. Does it matter? I suppose that being a Reference must have some type of advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I've an elaborated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176569/4157431). The code is

```
private ArrayList<String> docRefToString(ArrayList<DocumentReference> products) {
    ArrayList<String> newProducts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (DocumentReference product : products) {
        newProducts.add(product.getPath());
    }
    return newProducts;
}

private ArrayList<DocumentReference> docStringToDoc(ArrayList<String> products) {
    ArrayList<DocumentReference> newProducts = new ArrayList<DocumentReference>();
    for (String product : products) {
        newProducts.add(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(product));
    }
    return newProducts;
}
```

And in the Parcel implementation ..

```
private Request(Parcel in) {
    ...
    ArrayList<String> strProducts = in.createStringArrayList();
    this.products = docStringToDoc(strProducts);
    ...
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    ...
    dest.writeStringList(docRefToString(this.products));
    ...
}
```