# Parcel: unable to marshal value com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, parcelable

I store a list of references in the Cloud Firestore. When I get the data I it gives me this error:

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@44bef898"

I've searched on the internet but didn't find any solution. Thank you in advance

User.kt

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
import kotlinx.android.parcel.RawValue

@Parcelize
data class User(
    val bio: String? = null,
    val email: String? = null,
    val followers: @RawValue List<DocumentReference>? = null,
    val following: @RawValue List<DocumentReference>? = null,
    val picture: String? = null,
    val uid: String? = null,
    val username: String? = null
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: I think, `DocumentReference` is not `Parcelable`. How do you store a list of items?

Comment: Do you mean a list of DocumentReference? Because I can use DocumentReference itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference

Because your `User` class implements Parcelable, and all the fields inside it should also implement Parcelable, which doesn't, since both properties `followers` and `following`, are of type `List<DocumentReference>` and [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) does **not** implement Parcelable, nor Serializable. To solve this, you should check my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore DocumentReference Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288373/firestore-documentreference-serialization)

And use the String path that exists in each DocumentReference object.